# Patch file that works on different base commits?

Tags: git, patch

I have a patch that changes a file `foo.txt`. It was generated using a diff from commit `a`. However, now I want to apply this patch on top of commit `b` but this will fail if `foo.txt` is different in commit `a` vs commit `b`.

- Is it possible to create a patch that just replaces `foo.txt`, regardless of what it is applied on top of?
- If not, is there an alternative to patch files that I can use that supports this behaviour?

EDIT: Should also note that I do not need to be able to reverse the application of the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Existing patch tools are explicitly designed *not* to replace files that *don't* match, based on the fact that historically, this has proven to be a bad idea.

It is, of course, possible to roll your own patch software (not using `git apply` for instance) that does whatever you want it to do.

Given that you have cross-posted this to `git`, consider the fact that `git diff` output includes an `index:` line:

```
diff --git a/GIT-VERSION-GEN b/GIT-VERSION-GEN
index 216beefc50..d1a2814ec7 100755
--- a/GIT-VERSION-GEN
+++ b/GIT-VERSION-GEN
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 #!/bin/sh

 GVF=GIT-VERSION-FILE
-DEF_VER=v2.20.0
+DEF_VER=v2.20.1

 LF='
 '
```

Using `--full-index` expands this line:

```
index 216beefc50d54d132991636d5f049ea0916f1696..d1a2814ec7e415a525e58ac234df8184a2d0f93c 100755
```

The two big ugly hash IDs here are those of the "before" and "after" image of the file.  This enables Git to do a full three-way merge if necessary.  (The `100755` at the end, or `100644` in other cases, gives the `+x` or `-x` status of the file for a `git update-index --chmod=` option.)

Suppose, for instance, you wish to apply a patch to (as you said) `foo.txt` where the patch is based on commit A, but the current version of `foo.txt` is instead commit `B`.  The `index` line tells Git: *the hash ID of the version of `foo.txt` is <...>* (where the missing part is from `git rev-parse A:foo.txt`, i.e., the blob stored in commit `A`).  Git can therefore extract commit `A` from the repository, apply the patch successfully to `A:foo.txt`, and produce the correct updated file since the patch will now apply.  Now that Git has the "before" and "after" images, it can diff the "before" image against your current `B:foo.txt` as well, so that it knows *what you changed*.

Git can now put each of these three files somewhere—really, into the index, at slots 1, 2, and 3, just like in any other merge-based operation.  That gives Git the ability to do a regular three-way merge on the three inputs (base, ours, theirs) and either complete the merge on its own, or give you the chance to resolve conflicts.

Using this same basic idea, you can, if you like—it's not really a good idea in general—use the `index` line to find the blob, patch it (with guaranteed success since the patch applies *to* that `A:foo.txt` file), and use the resulting file directly.